# Oracle database - select a minimum of a select result

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I'd like to get the minimum value of a column returned by a select statement:

```
select lead(place) over (order by place) - place as gap
from viewers
```

I wanted to do it using the where clause, but apparently I cannot refer to my 'gap' column in the condition.

Answer (score 6):

You have to do it as a subquery:

```
select min(gap) from (
select lead(place) over (order by place) - place as gap
from viewers)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just treat the result given by **your query** as a **table from which** **you want to select minimum** .

```
 select min(gap) as MinimumGap 
    from (
          select lead(place) over (order by place) - place as gap
          from viewers 
         ) ;
```